# Error in PHP FreeTDS MSSQL Connection, supplied argument is not a valid link

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

I'm connecting to my MSSQL database remotely using PHP, MSSQL with FreeTDS by a CentOS cPanel Hosting.

And I'm getting this error, couldn't fixed after trying hours and hours...

```
Warning: mssql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-Link resource in /home/mrcskncn/public_html/process.php on line 71

Warning: mssql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in /home/mrcskncn/public_html/process.php on line 72
```

Here is the deal:

```
$dbc = mssql_connect($datasource, $datauser, $datapass) or die('Dam server!');
$selected = mssql_select_db($database, $dbc) or die('Dam db!');

$query_verify_account = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE AccountID = '$Account'";
$qry = mssql_query($dbc, $query_verify_account);
$line = mssql_fetch_array($qry);

if (isset($line["AccountID"])) {
    echo "This username is not available.";
}
```

What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch the parameters around in your call to mssql_query()

```
$qry = mssql_query($query_verify_account, $dbc);
```